# Is there a way to search multiple keywords in a Saved Search on NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am creating a Saved Search for my team where users can filter by different parameters but the most important one is a ‘Keyword’ field where we have multiple text strings separated by commas. Eg: One could be (Horses, Apples, Cows, Carrots, Balloons) and another could be (Apples, Cake,  Silver, Horses, Bananas)

I want to be able to use the free text search field to look up all rows where I can find a relevant entry.

Eg. Let’s say I type “Apples” and “Horses”. I want to see all entries where these are found together.

I have tried setting the criteria to “Contains” but can’t seem to use operators in the input field. I have also tried to use expressions but got You cannot use an expression builder criteria filter as an available filter" as an error.

I’m not familiar with NetSuite but willing to learn. I was able to create this in Google Sheets. Since we already store our information on NS already, I want to find a way to do it there. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the saved search, you can just specify a default value that will be used in the initial search load (e.g. contains Apples). In the Available Filters tab, select the same filter and check Show in Filter Region.

When users run the saved search, they can change the criteria by typing into the field and pressing Tab after (if you press Enter instead of Tab, the results will be downloaded into a CSV file instead of being displayed in the page). In your example, they should type 'apples%horses' then press Tab.

Additional reference: https://www.sikich.com/insight/using-formula-values-as-available-filters-in-netsuite-saved-searches/

Update:
Use 'has keywords' instead of 'contains' in the filter. When viewing the results, separate keywords with a comma. Example: 'apples, horses'

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Seems to be headed in the right direction but I saw some discrepancies. If I look up "horses%apples" I see 3 rows but if I switch it around like "apples%horses" I see 2. 

They are spelt the same way in all the rows. Is this an expected outcome?

Comment: Yes, that's expected. The % stands for any number of characters. "horses%apples" is not the same as "apples%horses" - % could be anything in between the two words but the order is followed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. Is there any way to make the search more powerful - so that the order/ number of keywords doesn't matter? I was able to achieve this using queries on Google Sheets. Is it possible to do this NS?

Comment: Hello, I tried that but didn't get any results. I can choose 'Has Keywords' from the Available Filters menu (Default Text Field Filter) but it doesn't show when I'm selecting the 'Criteria'.

Comment: Not sure why you won't be able to find 'has keywords' in the criteria tab. If you're filtering text fields, it should be there. This works in my account.